# applying lm to multiple datasets

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, lm

Below are 4 datasets (I've just created them randomly for the sake of providing a reproducible code). I created a list of these so I could apply "lm" to these multiple datasets at once :

```
H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))   
C<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=FALSE)))
R<-data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:30,10,rep=TRUE)))
E<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:40,10,rep=FALSE)))

dsets<-list(H,C,R,E)
models<-lapply(dsets,function(x)lm(X1~.,data=x))
lapply(models,summary)
```

The variables in each of the datasets are different (in count as well as names. However,if you run the code they will all be x1,x2..and so on).  The first column/variable in each will be the response and rest would be the independent variables.

This code works but not on my actual dataset. Since my datasets have actual names for variables, I used the position of the variable instead as below:

```
   dsets<-list(H,C,R,E)
   models<lapply(dsets,function(x)lm(x[,1]~.,data=x))
   lapply(models,summary)
```

Using the above, the results are messed up. It also includes the response variable as the independent variable.

Could anyone assist?

EDIT: I realized that x[,1] is calling the whole column and not the column name

```
   models<lapply(dsets,function(x)lm(colnames(x)[1]~.,data=x))
   lapply(models,summary)
```

but this doesn't work either. I get the following error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = colnames(H[1]) ~ ., data = H, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Var1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
models <- lapply(dsets, 
             function(data){
               lm(reformulate(termlabels=".", response=names(data)[1]), data)
             })
```

`reformulate` allows you to construct a formula from `character` strings.

Comment: Awsome ! this worked well. But could you tell me what was wrong with my code? and what does termlabels="." does?

Comment: Ok,looks like termlabels="." is just saying use all variables in the dataset

Comment: @oivemaria Yup you got it!

Comment: @oivemaria Your code was wrong because when R goes to evaluate that formulae is evaluates `colnames(x)[1]` and returns a character vector.  So basically it is saying the character `'Var1'`, length 1, is a function of the rows in your data set.  Clearly, not what you intended :)